# File upload for jqGrid in MVC architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, jqgrid

Can any one point me to a demo of file upload in jqGrid using MVC architecture. I had been looking for the posts for file upload, but most of the posts are for php.

This is the colModel which I had added

```
[
 colModel: [{ name: 'expenseDate', index: 'expenseDate', align: "center", sorttype: "date" },
        { name: 'customerProject', index: 'customerProject', align: "center", sorttype: "string" },
        { name: 'accountType', index: 'accountType', align: "center"},
        { name: 'expenseDetails', index: 'expenseDetails', align: "left" },
        { name: 'expenseAmount', index: 'expenseAmount', align: "right" },
        { name: 'reimbursibleExpense', index: 'reimbursibleExpense', align: "center" },
        { name: 'billableExpense', index: 'billableExpense', align: "center" },
        **{
            name: 'receipt', index: 'receipt', align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'file'
            , editoptions: { enctype: "multipart/form-data" }
            , align: 'center', search: false, width: 500}
        },**
        { name: 'clas', index: 'clas', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
        { name: 'merchant', index: 'merchant', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
        { name: 'ExpId', index: 'ExpId', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } }
```

But I am not getting how to post the image after it is selected. Once I click on browse I get a popup to select a file. after file is selected I can the physical path being displayed in the input tag. But now how do I post this image back to my controller?

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC HTML Helper for the jqGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424640/ASP-NET-MVC-HTML-Helper-for-the-jqGrid), [jqGrid and ASP.NET MVC](http://tpeczek.blogspot.in/2011/03/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-form-editing-with.html) . Have you searched for it ?

Comment: I had checked both the links which you had provided. If use a HTML helper also then also I am unable to add the file upload controls to the grid. And the second link you provided requires integration with TinyMCE. Actually the scenario is that there have been already a lot of library files included in the application I we are trying to develop and the aim is to reduce any other dependencies. So we were trying to do it with existing jqGrid only. any how thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: At present I gave edittype as file in the colmodel. And I am getting the browse link in the edit row in the grid. But I am not getting hit the controller method after the image has been selected to upload

Comment: Please post your code, if you have any errors or so. As you know how to implement `jqGrid`, you dont need to ask for it